# How can I create a device node from the init_module code of a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mknod

I am writing a module for the Linux kernel, and I want to create some device nodes in the init() function:

```c
int init_module(void)
{
    Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);

    // Now I want to create device nodes
    // with the returned major number
}
```

I also want the kernel to assign a minor number for my first node, and then I will assign the other nodes' minor numbers by myself.

How can I do this in the code? I don’t want to create devices from the shell using [mknod()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To have more control over the device numbers and the device creation, you could do the following steps (instead of `register_chrdev()`):

1. Call `alloc_chrdev_region()` to get a major number and a range of minor numbers to work with.
2. Create a device class for your devices with `class_create()`.
3. For each device, call `cdev_init()` and `cdev_add()` to add the character device to the system.
4. For each device, call `device_create()`. As a result, among other things, [Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) will create device nodes for your devices. There isn’t any need for `mknod()` or the like. `device_create()` also allows you to control the names of the devices.

There are probably many examples of this on the Internet, and [one of them is here](https://github.com/euspectre/kedr/blob/master/sources/examples/sample_target/cfake.c).

Comment: Sorry for digging this up from the past, but is there an equivalent method of doing this when the license is not GPL? class_create cannot be used with non-GPL licenses.

Comment: @Piotr: actually, I don't know if it exists.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for sharing. Question: how do I cleanup the registered device(s) and file(s) under /dev/my_dev_files ?

Comment: @Nikita Vorontsov, the following cleanup operations are executed: `device_destroy` (it also takes care of deleting the device node), `cdev_del` unregisters the device from the kernel. After each device has been deleted, `class_destroy` is called to delete the class and then - `unregister_chrdev_region`. What is done when creating the devices is undone in reverse order, as usual.

Comment: @Eugene - A great answer !! Thanks. I have one question - Isn't the device_create() should be called before the call to cdev_add() ?

Comment: I think `device_create()` should be called after `cdev_add()`. `cdev_add()` prepares the in kernel structures to maintain the device and `device_create()` makes the device available to the user space among other things. And as soon as you make your device available to the user space, that device should be ready to handle requests from there.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for your reply. I'm following the Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition by O'Reilly - and up to this stage they don't mention the device_create method, but they do introduce the cdev_add and they mention the same as thing you mention only for the cdev_add method. I guess that later on when they do call the device_create in their samples they will call them both in the order you mentioned. Thanks for enlightening that point out (see the end of section 3.4 to see my point: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4). Many thanks !!

Comment: @Eugene BTW - in the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327360/1971003 the cdev_add() is also called after device_create().

Comment: LDD3 is great, but yes, it is a bit outdated. Previously, one would create device "files" with mknod. device_create() become available later. As for other examples where cdev_add() is called after device_create() - well, I do not know if it is a right thing to do and prefer to play safer. One can try to build such example module and try to load it while repeatedly trying to access the devices it creates at the same time. If the kernel has no protection w.r.t. such cases, it may crash. Or may be, it detects "uninitialized" devices somehow - I just do not know.

Comment: Sorry to dig it up but I have a question in this. After the device file etc is created, I would like to read, write etc to it. For this I have to change the file perms using chmod every time I load the module. Is there an automated way to do this.

Comment: You can use an udev rule, for example, to set the desired permissions automatically. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111593/allow-non-root-user-to-read-write-dev-files

Answer (score 15):

```c
static int __init ofcd_init(void) /* Constructor */
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Welcome!");
    if (alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 1, "char_dev") < 0)    //$cat /proc/devices
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv")) == NULL)    //$ls /sys/class
    {
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    if (device_create(cl, NULL, first, NULL, "mynull") == NULL)    //$ls /dev/
    {
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);
    if (cdev_add(&c_dev, first, 1) == -1)
    {
        device_destroy(cl, first);
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `cdev_add()` should be called before `device_create()`. That seems to be the more common order.

Comment: Code might be clear if you would use goto like kernel uses.

Comment: Your cleanup is missing `cdev_del`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45531867/895245

Answer (score 9):

**Minimal runnable example**

Minimized from other answers. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/68af3477cce1cd22566edce2651f54cf8c184a91/kernel_module/character_device_create.c) with test setup.

```c
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h> /* register_chrdev, unregister_chrdev */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h> /* seq_read, seq_lseek, single_release */

#define NAME "lkmc_character_device_create"

static int major = -1;
static struct cdev mycdev;
static struct class *myclass = NULL;

static int show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    seq_printf(m, "abcd");
    return 0;
}

static int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return single_open(file, show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .llseek = seq_lseek,
    .open = open,
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = seq_read,
    .release = single_release,
};

static void cleanup(int device_created)
{
    if (device_created) {
        device_destroy(myclass, major);
        cdev_del(&mycdev);
    }
    if (myclass)
        class_destroy(myclass);
    if (major != -1)
        unregister_chrdev_region(major, 1);
}

static int myinit(void)
{
    int device_created = 0;

    /* cat /proc/devices */
    if (alloc_chrdev_region(&major, 0, 1, NAME "_proc") < 0)
        goto error;
    /* ls /sys/class */
    if ((myclass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, NAME "_sys")) == NULL)
        goto error;
    /* ls /dev/ */
    if (device_create(myclass, NULL, major, NULL, NAME "_dev") == NULL)
        goto error;
    device_created = 1;
    cdev_init(&mycdev, &fops);
    if (cdev_add(&mycdev, major, 1) == -1)
        goto error;
    return 0;
error:
    cleanup(device_created);
    return -1;
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    cleanup(1);
}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Santilli - +1 for the great example.