# Creating a device file: Linux device driver

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device

How to create a device file when I do not know the minor and major number (i.e. by using dynamic registration)  without using `mknod` or `MAKEDEV`.

Comment: You should learn a lot more about `udev`

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to dynamically assign a major number to a char device on insertion, use:

int alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t *dev, unsigned int firstminor, unsigned int count, char *name);

From Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition.  Google it you can get the entire book for free along with tons of great source code for messing with drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the codes provided in the LDD3 are obsolete now. So, use this github repo to download example codes of LDD3: https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3