# mknod at linux startup

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have a device which I added to /etc/modules, previously it was added by insmod then mknod..

I want to add mknod command at kernel boot..

```
  # load driver
/sbin/insmod -f ./${module}.${suf} $* o_dbg=1 || exit 1

# Get driver major number
major=`awk "\\$2==\"$module\" {print \\$1}" /proc/devices`

mknod /dev/${device}0 c $major 0
```

1- I added the module to /lib/modules/`uname -r`/

2- debmod -a

but I don't know how to make mknod automatically

Comment: may could help :   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks,but is there a way like automatically use mknode without script, like adding module name to /etc/modules

Comment: I used script for now, I add mknod commands in `/ect/rc.local` but as described before are there a way to "mknod" automatically without script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is having `udev` or `mdev` then you can write rules to create device nodes automatically. Otherwise, you can manually call `sys_mknod` from your module code. Make sure that `sys_mknod` is exported.

See also: [Create a device node in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/create-a-device-node-in-code)

Comment: Thanks, But unfortunately I do not have the module code, I have the .ko file.