# How to create an event# device for a virtual input device (/dev/input/js3) in linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, input, linux-kernel, kernel-module, joystick

i am writing a linux kernel module which takes N of real /dev/input/js# devices and proxifies them as a single /dev/input/js3 device. Currently my module is creating /dev/input/js3 just fine, `jstest` is happy with it, but not the real applications. I guess (strace'd) it is so because i have no matching pair of /dev/input/event# for my virtual js3 device. How do i create one from my module?

Here is my module's source, which probably has numerous of issues, but mostly working: https://github.com/iamtakingiteasy/unijoy/blob/master/unijoy.c

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, you can use

```
1. class_create to create the class specified for the device,
2. device_create to create the device node
3. cdev_init to initialize and 
4. cdev_add to add the device to the /dev list
```

For example you can refer the below link :[Create a device node in kernel module](http://coherentmusings.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/device-node-creation-without-using-mknod/)

Comment: You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/create-a-device-node-in-code this for more understanding