# unregister_chrdev does not remove device from /dev/

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm running `unregister_chrdev(major, "mod_name");` but I can still the the device in `ls -l /dev/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you create a device? I think you need `device_create()/device_destroy()` pair for that. It seems that `unregister_chrdev` unregisters major number related to all devices, while device is represented by the pair of minor and major numbers

Comment: `register_chrdev(0, "mod_name", &fops);`

Comment: And this creates node in devtmpfs? Any way, please take a look to that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5973426/2709018 . It shows the correct way of creating character device.

Answer (score 1):

`register_chrdev(9)` and `unregister_chrdev(9)` do not actually create or remove files in `/dev` directory. You should create them beforehand by a load script. Deletion is the same, you should delete them manually.

See [scull example](https://github.com/duxing2007/ldd3-examples-3.x/tree/master/scull), scull_load creates a char file (with the same major number as your module) after loading the module with `insmod`. scull_unload is similar, removes files under `/dev` after unloading with `rmmod`.

As @myaut [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580159/unregister-chrdev-does-not-remove-device-from-dev/29581824#comment47309984_29580159), this can also be done with `device_create`, but this is a GPL-only function and if your module is not licensed under GPL, you will have to create the files manually.