# where do char device appear after cdev_add() registers successfully with major on 117.

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written basic char driver.

Registration of char device with kernel has been done using cdev_alloc, cdev_init, cdev_add.
Major = 117, Minor = 1.

cdev_add function retrun success. 
I am trying to check whether char device created or not.
I dont find any device under /dev/ or /dev/char with major no 117.

register_chrdev is not going to be use in the latest kernel, where we give NAME.
but cdev_add perform char device registration with kernel using major number only.

I am confused with the latest kernel behavior.

Do i need to use register_chrdev along with cdev_add ?
or
Do i need to use mknod commad to showup device in /dev/ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a device node in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/create-a-device-node-in-code)

Answer (score 5):

**`cdev`** is the char device representation of the kernel and is to associate cdev with a set of file_operations. These file_operations are performed on a device node, typically present under /dev or depending on you where you create a device node.

**cdev_init()** is used to associate a cdev with a set of file_operations. Finally cdev_add() is called on the device to make it live, such that, the user could access them.

**Now, while this is done, it doesn't mean that the device node is created for you**.

This is done manually either by using **mknod utility** or using **device_create()** function. Device nodes are generally associated with a class. Thus, we need to create a class first(using class_create()) and then create device nodes using that class.

This is an example how to get device node.

```
struct class *my_class;
struct cdev my_cdev[N_MINORS];    
dev_t dev_num;

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    int i;
    dev_t curr_dev;

    /* Request the kernel for N_MINOR devices */
    alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_num, 0, N_MINORS, "my_driver");

    /* Create a class : appears at /sys/class */
    my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "my_driver_class");

    /* Initialize and create each of the device(cdev) */
    for (i = 0; i < N_MINORS; i++) {

        /* Associate the cdev with a set of file_operations */
        cdev_init(&my_cdev[i], &fops);

        /* Build up the current device number. To be used further */
        curr_dev = MKDEV(MAJOR(dev_num), MINOR(dev_num) + i);

        /* Create a device node for this device. Look, the class is
         * being used here. The same class is associated with N_MINOR
         * devices. Once the function returns, device nodes will be
         * created as /dev/my_dev0, /dev/my_dev1,... You can also view
         * the devices under /sys/class/my_driver_class.
         */
        device_create(my_class, NULL, curr_dev, NULL, "my_dev%d", i);

        /* Now make the device live for the users to access */
        cdev_add(&my_cdev[i], curr_dev, 1); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> register_chrdev is not going to be use in the latest kernel, where we
>   give NAME?

register_chrdev() is the older way which was using in kernel 2.4, but in kernel 2.6 is replaced with register_chrdev_region() and   alloc_chardev_region().

1. register_chrdev_region() if you know ahead of time exactly which device numbers you want.
2. alloc_chrdev_region() for dynamically allocated a device number, done by kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sumit.
I was referring to 2.4 kernel doc and entered into loop.
Your explanation cleared off confusions in a single shot.

Comment: @VijayKalyanam Welcome :-)

Comment: Hi Sumit,
I have modified the code according to new kernel behavior.
still i don't see device is not listed under /dev/.

This is the code.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Hi Sumit,
I got the resolution. there is a bug in my code. Corrected it.
Now my own module is working and is operation.

Thank you for your response Bro.